# Location of test automation sources

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, cucumber, fitnesse

I'm busy with orientating myself on test automation. Think about Fitnesse, Cucumber or Robot Now I'm doubting where to put my tests. Roughly there are three options.

1) Same project as the application under test
2) In a separate project in the same (Git) repo
3) Seperate project in a seperate (Git) repo.

What is, if there is, common to do? And why?

Answer (score 1):

My best practise is to put the tests in the same Git repo in it's own module so I can access the application code and the test code in the same branch. And not just me, but the CI/CD tool in use as well.

Comment: With unit/integration testing i need to acces application code. So I put thos there as well. What i'm talking about is functional testing an deployed application.

Comment: For functional testing a deployed application I use the same strategy as Koen. The test code goes into the same repo, so the test code can evolve with the application code without the need maintain some convention (or worse: configuration) to determine which version of the test to run against with version of the (deployed) application.

Answer (score 1):

I would not consider anything else than keeping production code and test code in the same repository.

My main arguments are

- I want the tests to be executed each time the production code changes and my CI server picks up the change
- Test code and production code is maintained at the same time and by the same people, keeping them in separated repositories just makes life hard

Comment: Thats true when you talk about Junit tests or even interation tests. But when you're talking about functional/acceptance tests is different I think And when you execute over multiple applications it must be seperated.

Comment: I organize my tests the same way when I implement acceptance tests as well. I don't want them to be maintained somewhere else, they are just as important as the product and should therefore be maintained at the same location.

Comment: What is the difference between tests and functional/acceptance tests from your perspective? To me a functional test is anything that verifies that the product does the right thing. They may be implemented at a unit level or they may be implemented at a higher level through the products UI.

Comment: Having the same test code for many products suggests to me that they really are the same product and that you haven't discovered it yet. You would probably want to go in the direction of a mono repo, as many organizations do these days, and thus end up version controlling the test code in the same repositoy are the rest of the production code.